# 'Priority' is imported from both packages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

A simple function as below:

```
void showNotification(RemoteNotification remoteNotification) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      "com.domain.app",
      "A App",
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,       <-----
    );
```

Error message:

> Error: 'Priority' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_specifics/android/enums.dart'.

I tried somebody's accepted answer like

```
import 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart' hide Priority;
```

But don't know why, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fix it by

```dart
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_specifics/android/enums.dart' as AndroidEnums;

....

void showNotification(RemoteNotification remoteNotification) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      "com.domain.app",
      "A App",
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: AndroidEnums.Priority.high,       <-----
    );
```

but still don't know why `hide` doesn't work.